# A mysql query about the times of train transferring

Tags: mysql

A table has the id of train and the id of station of the train.

```
train_id,   station_id
 1            1
 1            2
 1            3
 2            3
 2            4
 3            4
 3            5
```

I want to check whether I can from station 1 to station 5 by transferring train 2 times. Ans: 1-2-3 transfer at station 3, station 4.
I want to check whether I can from station 1 to station 4 by transferring train 1 times. Ans: 1-2 transfer at station 3.

My idea is to join the table by the times of transferring, but I don't know how to join only when the train has common station.

Comment: Start with this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding And I wish you a good luck on trying to do that in pure sql

Comment: If I only want to check whether I can go from station A to station B by transfer once, do you have a SQL way?

Comment: Technically - yes. You select all `train_id` by `station_id`, then select all stations they stop on, then you join all the other trains that share stations and see if the destination point is there. It will only work if you only change one train.

Comment: Don't we need to know something about the direction of travel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I realize it's inefficient, but I warned that you wouldn't do that in SQL

Just for fun created a sketch that works for one transfer:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT l.train_id s1,
                    r.train_id s2
      FROM routes l
INNER JOIN routes r
     WHERE (l.train_id, r.train_id) IN (SELECT l.train_id tl,
                                               r.train_id tr
                                          FROM routes l
                                    INNER JOIN routes r ON l.station_id = r.station_id
                                         WHERE l.train_id IN (SELECT train_id
                                                                FROM routes
                                                               WHERE station_id = 1))
                                                                       --         ^
                                                                       -- start point

       AND r.station_id = 4 -- <-- end point
```

This query outputs the possible routes in terms of train numbers, you can find the transfer stations from it easily.

Some explanation:

1. The most nested query selects all the trains that stop on the initial station
2. Next query finds all the trains that share any stations with every train from #1
3. The outer query matches the combinations that have the start and the end point in their route

PS: it would be possible to make it a bit more readable if mysql supported `CTE`s (`WITH`), but it does not :-)

sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/796183/14